# Entity Framework: Find Number Of Rows That Will Be Affected By A Change

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

Using Entity Framework (8.0.3), I'm looking to find the number of rows that would be affected, should one call `DbContext.SaveChanges()`, without actually saving the changes to the database, to be implemented something along the lines of this:

```cs
int numberOfChanges = MyDbContext.NumberOfChanges;
Console.WriteLine($"Save {numberOfChanges} changes? (y/n)");
if (Console.ReadKey() == 'y') 
{ // ...
```

I've looked through my class that implements DbContext and found nothing that suggests a representation of the number of altered rows.

My ideas to solve this include:

- Taking a "snapshot" of the database as it was, saving changes, extracting the number of rows affected, then re-setting the database to how it was before (slow, memory-intensive, and requires extra code maintenance)
- Using a custom getter/setter on every `DbSet<T>` in the implementation of DbContext (messy, and again requires extra maintenance in expanding the implementation)

Is there a better way to find the number of changes that will be made on a `DbContext.SaveChanges()` call?

Comment: check DbContext ChangeTracker property. It contains added, modified and deleted entities

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the entities that already tracking by EF and then check their states.

In EF Core we have 5 states:

- Added
- Modified
- Deleted
- Unchanged
- Detached

```cs
var entries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries();

foreach(var entry in entries)
{
  if(entry.State is EntityState.Added or EntityState.Modified or EntityState.Deleted)
  {
    // here you can count affected row
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out what was changed via `dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()`.
In your case it could look something like

```
int numberOfChanges = MyDbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count();
Console.WriteLine($"Save {numberOfChanges} changes? (y/n)");
```